# Oracle pl/sql: Encountered the symbol ""

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I am trying to create this trigger that checks whether the number of availabletickets is greater than 0 and if it isn't, it throws an error while booking but while creating the trigger, i am getting the following error

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ""
```

here is my code:

```
create or replace trigger booked_ticket before insert OR UPDATE on booking for each row
declare
    v_available NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT AVAILABLETICKETS into v_available from HALLSEAT WHERE HALLSEAT .STAGEID=:NEW.STAGEID;
IF v_available<1 THEN
 Raise_Application_Error(-20343, 'You cant book');
END IF;
end;​
```

Comment: Do you mean to have a space here? `HALLSEAT .STAGEID`

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking an MCVE makes it hard to answer](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) I am also missing line and column number of the error.

Comment: You might consider providing a more informative and better spelled error message than `'You cant book'`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it compiles OK (I've created dummy tables, just to make the trigger compile). I didn't modify your code at all, simply copy/pasted it into my SQL*Plus session.

Though, I'd suggest you to

- learn how to format code and make it easier to read.
- edit your question and copy/paste **your** SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you exactly did and how Oracle responded. It'll indicate the place where you get the error, as just saying that there's one doesn't help much

---

```
SQL> create table booking (stageid number);

Table created.

SQL> create table hallseat (availabletickets number, stageid number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger booked_ticket before insert OR UPDATE on booking for each row
  2  declare
  3      v_available NUMBER;
  4  begin
  5    SELECT AVAILABLETICKETS into v_available from HALLSEAT WHERE HALLSEAT .STAGEID=:NEW.STAGEID;
  6  IF v_available<1 THEN
  7   Raise_Application_Error(-20343, 'You cant book');
  8  END IF;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT**]

Though, yes - GUI (SQL Developer) reports the error in line 7 + column 7. It is this line:

```
 Raise_Application_Error(-20343, 'You cant book');
      ^
      here
```

As if there's some "unrecognized" character. I reviewed that code in Notepad++, set it to display *all characters*, but none (except CR/LF) appeared, so I'm not sure what is the real reason for that error.

The simplest way to "fix" it is to delete everything you have (I mean, that trigger) and write (type) it once again. Should be OK (was when I tried it, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Very sketchy error: you have an invisible character ASCII(8203) after your line 9 "end;" statement. Copy and paste this trigger instead and you'll be fine.

```
create or replace trigger booked_ticket before insert OR UPDATE on booking for each row
declare
    v_available NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT AVAILABLETICKETS into v_available from HALLSEAT 
  WHERE HALLSEAT .STAGEID=:NEW.STAGEID;
IF v_available<1 THEN
 Raise_Application_Error(-20343, 'You cant book');
END IF;
end;​
```